# Optaplanner IllegalArgumentException: The valueRangeProviderRef does not appear in valueRangeProvideIds

Tags: java, optaplanner

***Using Boolean planning variable defined in the planning entity as:***

```
@PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = {"selectedRange"})
public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

*and in the planning solution I define the value range provider as:*

```
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "selectedRange")
List<Boolean> getValueRange() {
     return Arrays.asList(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
}
public List<Boolean> getBooleanList() {
    return selectedList;
}

public void setBooleanList(List<Boolean> selectedList) {
    this.selectedList = selectedList;
}
```

***I received the following error:***

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>
> The `entityClass` has a `PlanningVariable` annotated property (selected)
>   with a `valueRangeProviderRef` (selectedRange) that does not exist on a
>   registered `PlanningSolution` or `PlanningEntity`.
>
> The `valueRangeProviderRef` (selectedRange) does not appear in
>   `valueRangeProvideIds` ([]).

***I can't recognize the problem cause.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I would say: You're missing a `@ValueRangeProvider` on a property of your solution class. But it looks like you have it. For some reason it's just not picking up it when it reflects over your planning solution class.

A) If you're using a `6.3.0.Final` or later, your code should work. If you're using an older version, it's probably because the `getValueRange()` method isn't public (6.3 fixes that IIRC).

B) If the `getValueRange()` method is defined on a superclass instead of on the actual planning solution class, then it will only work if that superclass is known as a proper planning solution class too IIRC.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I'm Using version 6.2.0, I added public to the public List<Boolean> getValueRange() and the error disappeared.